# Unirest cannot recognise gson mapper

Tags: java, json, gson, unirest

Could you please explain why unirest cannot recognise gson mapper dependency in pom.xml?
As a result, I cannot use method `asJson()` as it throws exception:

> Caused by: kong.unirest.UnirestConfigException: No Json Parsing
> Implementation Provided Please add a dependency for a Unirest JSON
> Engine. This can be one of:     com.konghq   unirest-object-mappers-gson
> ${latest-version}

**The pom.xml looks as follows:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.konghq</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-object-mappers-gson</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>LATEST</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a bug in the latest version of the library (unirest-java 4.0.0-RC2). Using unirest-java 4.0.0-RC1 fixed this issue for me.